# jQuery - replace in map function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace, map-function

I'm using the following map function to create HTML

```
 createHtml: function (data) {
        var values = data.map(function(val) {
            return this.li.replace("{{TEXT}}", val.name);
        },{li:this.values });
        this.$ele.html(this.lis.replace("{{NAME}}","cd-view").replace("
                              {{ITEMS}}", values.join("")));
    }
```

which works fine by displaying the user name on my HTML but when I modify the above code to the following to add id attribute to these usernames, my html renders id attribute as {{ID}} instead 1 or any id value

```
 createHtml: function (data) {
        var values = data.map(function(val) {
                   **this.li.replace("{{ID}}", item.id);**   -- added newly
            return this.li.replace("{{USER}}", val.name);
        },{li:this.values });
        this.$ele.html(this.lis.replace("{{NAME}}","cd-view").replace("
                              {{ITEMS}}", values.join("")));
    }
```

can anyone point me where the issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because `replace()` returns a string, it does not affect the original `this.li` value.

To fix this you need to call `replace()` to change the `{{ID}}`and store the result. Then you can call `replace()` again on this result to change the `{{USER}}`, something like this:

```js
createHtml: function(data) {
  var values = data.map(function(val) {
    var str = this.li.replace("{{ID}}", item.id);
    return str.replace("{{USER}}", val.name);
  }, {
    li: this.values
  });
  this.$ele.html(this.lis.replace("{{NAME}}", "cd-view").replace("{{ITEMS}}", values.join("")));
}
```